# (1,0)-forms/bundle problem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, holomorphic-bundles

I'm reading the book of Andrei Moroianu, "Lectures on kahler geometry" and at the page 69 is this exercise:

[image]

Can some one give me a hint? I'm kinda new to the subject.

Comment: I'm rusty on this kind of thing, but I would start with the case $M = \mathbb R^{2n}$. I'm pretty sure this is ultimately just a statement about eigenspaces. Once you have the underlying linear algebraic fact identified, globalizing should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Just a small comment: Holomorphic $1$-forms on a complex manifold are a very special sort of $(1,0)$ form, so your title is a bit off. (And you really need an integrable almost complex structure for it to make sense.)

Comment: @TedShifrin  you are right!